# Android app crashes on one activity

Tags: java, android

I've written an app that first asks users to select some parameters for a reaction time game.  When it reaches the activity for the game itself, the app crashes.  The activity is supposed to change the screen color from red to green after a random time between 2 and 10 seconds and then start a timer. The timer stops when the user taps, thus measuring their reaction time to the color change. The following is the activity's code and my error log.  Please tell me if you see the reason for getting the **"unfortunately, the app has stopped"** message.

#### JAVA:

```
package com.dabaam.battlereaction;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Game extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{
    public static final String difficulty = "difficulty";
    public static final String mode = "mode";
    public Random r = new Random();
    int after = r.nextInt(10000 - 2000) + 2000;
    public long time1 = 0;
    public long time2 = 0;
    public long elapsed = 80085; //boobs by default
    public String ms_score = "boobs"; //boobs by default

    public void onCreate(Bundle b){
        super.onCreate(b);
        setContentView(R.layout.game_layout);
        new Timer().schedule(change(), after);
    }

    public LinearLayout glayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.gameLayout);

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // LinearLayout glayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.gameLayout);
        time2= System.nanoTime();
        elapsed = (time2-time1)/1000000;

        TextView score = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        ms_score = getString(R.string.score, elapsed);
        score.setText(ms_score);
        glayout.addView(score);

        return false;
    }

    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor") public TimerTask change() {
        // LinearLayout glayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.gameLayout);
        glayout.setBackgroundColor(R.color.Blue);
        time1= System.nanoTime();
        return null;
    }

}
```

#### Layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@color/red" >

</LinearLayout>
```

#### ERROR LOG:

```
07-01 19:16:03.777: W/asset(19731): Copying FileAsset 0x761e3178 (zip:/data/app/com.dabaam.battlereaction-2.apk:/resources.arsc) to buffer size 108276 to make it aligned.
07-01 19:16:03.897: I/Adreno-EGL(19731): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:316>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (CL4169980)
07-01 19:16:03.897: I/Adreno-EGL(19731): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version:  17.01.10.SPL
07-01 19:16:03.897: I/Adreno-EGL(19731): Build Date: 02/04/14 Tue
07-01 19:16:03.897: I/Adreno-EGL(19731): Local Branch: 
07-01 19:16:03.897: I/Adreno-EGL(19731): Remote Branch: 
07-01 19:16:03.897: I/Adreno-EGL(19731): Local Patches: 
07-01 19:16:03.897: I/Adreno-EGL(19731): Reconstruct Branch: 
07-01 19:16:05.659: W/dalvikvm(19731): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41642e18)
07-01 19:16:05.669: E/AndroidRuntime(19731): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-01 19:16:05.669: E/AndroidRuntime(19731): Process: com.dabaam.battlereaction, PID: 19731
07-01 19:16:05.669: E/AndroidRuntime(19731): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.dabaam.battlereaction/com.dabaam.battlereaction.Game}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-01 19:16:05.669: E/AndroidRuntime(19731):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2514)
07-01 19:16:05.669: E/AndroidRuntime(19731):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2653)
07-01 19:16:05.669: E/AndroidRuntime(19731):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
07-01 19:16:05.669: E/AndroidRuntime(19731):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
07-01 19:16:05.669: E/AndroidRuntime(19731):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-01 19:16:05.669: E/AndroidRuntime(19731):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
07-01 19:16:05.669: E/AndroidRuntime(19731):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
07-01 19:16:05.669: E/AndroidRuntime(19731):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-01 19:16:05.669: E/AndroidRuntime(19731):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-01 19:16:05.669: E/AndroidRuntime(19731):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1069)
07-01 19:16:05.669: E/AndroidRuntime(19731):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:885)
07-01 19:16:05.669: E/AndroidRuntime(19731):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-01 19:16:05.669: E/AndroidRuntime(19731): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-01 19:16:05.669: E/AndroidRuntime(19731):    at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1952)
07-01 19:16:05.669: E/AndroidRuntime(19731):    at com.dabaam.battlereaction.Game.<init>(Game.java:32)
07-01 19:16:05.669: E/AndroidRuntime(19731):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
07-01 19:16:05.669: E/AndroidRuntime(19731):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
07-01 19:16:05.669: E/AndroidRuntime(19731):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1079)
07-01 19:16:05.669: E/AndroidRuntime(19731):    at  android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2505)
07-01 19:16:05.669: E/AndroidRuntime(19731):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public LinearLayout glayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.gameLayout);
```

You cannot initialize fields that reference Views like this. `findViewById()` will crash if it runs before `super.onCreate()`. Additionally, it should run after `setContentView()`, or it will return null.

You should change this code into something like:

```
public LinearLayout glayout;

public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    super.onCreate(b);
    setContentView(R.layout.game_layout);
    glayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.gameLayout);
    new Timer().schedule(change(), after);
}
```